# Sending 'CLLocationManager *' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D';

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location, mkreversegeocoder

Im working through a weather app tutorial. I am having trouble getting the reverse geocode of the location. It keeps getting the error that is in the title. I get what it is telling me just stuck on how to fix it.

Heres the code snippet:

```
if (1)
{
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:locationManager];
    geocoder.delegate = self;
    [geocoder start];
}
else
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showWeatherFor:) withObject:@"95014"];
}
```

Like I said, Im still learning so an explanation would be nice as to why you did what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call location getter in the delegate method of CLLocation where you get the gps coordinates. The parameter of MKReverseGeocoder is a CLLocation and not CLLocationManager

```
# pragma mark LocationGetter Delegate Methods

- (void)newPhysicalLocation:(CLLocation *)location {

    //Geocoder is started only if a valid location is found.
    self.reverseGeocoder = [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:location] autorelease];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];

}
```

Comment: How do I call the location getter?

Comment: I thought I was starting to get the location with "startUpdatingLocation"